ESC * POS Image Printing
Bit of a strange one, that I just cannot fathom !
I am printing images direct to a Netum Thermal Printer. using GS V and a raster image I can get it to print fine however as this is an out of date approach I thought I would use ESC *.
Netum has confirmed they support the command but I'm having issues. I have written us a very simple example...
1) Send Printer Initialise command
2) Set the code page to 1252 (as i need £ signs)
3) Print some text 'Start of printer'
4) print the image......

 imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)0x1B, (byte)0x33, (byte)8 });    //ESC 3 8 
 imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)0x1B, (byte)0x2A, (byte)0 });    //ESC * 0
 imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)128, (byte)0x0 });               //128 0

//followed by a nice 8bit deep zigzag
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)4, (byte)8, (byte)16, (byte)32, (byte)64, (byte)128 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)128, (byte)64, (byte)32, (byte)16, (byte)8, (byte)4, (byte)2, (byte)1 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)4, (byte)8, (byte)16, (byte)32, (byte)64, (byte)128 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)128, (byte)64, (byte)32, (byte)16, (byte)8, (byte)4, (byte)2, (byte)1 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)4, (byte)8, (byte)16, (byte)32, (byte)64, (byte)128 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)128, (byte)64, (byte)32, (byte)16, (byte)8, (byte)4, (byte)2, (byte)1 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)4, (byte)8, (byte)16, (byte)32, (byte)64, (byte)128 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)128, (byte)64, (byte)32, (byte)16, (byte)8, (byte)4, (byte)2, (byte)1 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)4, (byte)8, (byte)16, (byte)32, (byte)64, (byte)128 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)128, (byte)64, (byte)32, (byte)16, (byte)8, (byte)4, (byte)2, (byte)1 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)4, (byte)8, (byte)16, (byte)32, (byte)64, (byte)128 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)128, (byte)64, (byte)32, (byte)16, (byte)8, (byte)4, (byte)2, (byte)1 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)4, (byte)8, (byte)16, (byte)32, (byte)64, (byte)128 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)128, (byte)64, (byte)32, (byte)16, (byte)8, (byte)4, (byte)2, (byte)1 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)4, (byte)8, (byte)16, (byte)32, (byte)64, (byte)128 });
imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { (byte)128, (byte)64, (byte)32, (byte)16, (byte)8, (byte)4, (byte)2, (byte)1 });

5) followed by a line feed imageCommand.Append(new byte[] { 0x0A }); as if i were to then print the next pass of the image. 

If I iterate that code above a number of times, I would expect the same results to be printed out each time! I certainly pass the same set of bytes each time... but I get this, sometimes it works ok, sometimes it produces odd lines ?
I use
public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, byte[] data) 

for sending data to the printer. Any ideas?

If you want a simple example of it not working, I have included a very simple console app,
using ThermalPrinting;

var printer = new Printer();

bool end = false;

while (!end)
{
    printer.Print();

    Console.WriteLine("Print again? y/n");
    var response = Console.ReadLine();

    end = response?.ToUpper() == "N";    
}

using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ThermalPrinting
{
    internal class PrinterCommands
    {
        public static readonly byte ESC = 0x1B; //ESC
        public static readonly byte Initialize = 0x40; //@
        public static readonly byte LineFeed = 0x0A; //LF
        public static readonly byte Asterix = 0x2A; //*
        public static readonly byte EightDotSingleDensity = 0x00; //0

        public static byte[] LineSpacing(int dots)
        {
            return new byte[] { (byte)0x1B, (byte)0x33, (byte)dots }; //ESC 3 dots
        }
    }

    public class RawPrinterHelper
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;
        }

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
            ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter,
            IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
            ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, int level,
            [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, int dwCount, out int dwWritten);

        // SendBytesToPrinter()
        // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
        // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the printer queue.
        // Returns true on success, false on failure.
        public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, int dwCount)
        {
            int dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            var hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            var di = new DOCINFOA();
            var bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = "VIP RAW PrinterDocument";
            di.pDataType = "RAW";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }

                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }

                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }

            // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
            // about why not.
            if (bSuccess == false)
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            return bSuccess;
        }

        public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, byte[] data)
        {
            var pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(data.Length); // Allocate unmanaged memory
            Marshal.Copy(data, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, data.Length); // copy bytes into unmanaged memory
            var retval = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, data.Length);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes); // Free the allocated unmanaged memory

            return retval;
        }
    }

    internal class Printer
    {
        protected ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> WriteBuffer { get; set; } = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();

        public void Print()
        {
            WriteBuffer.Clear();

            WriteBuffer.Enqueue([PrinterCommands.ESC, PrinterCommands.Initialize]); //ESC @
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue("Start printing".ToCharArray().Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray());
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue([PrinterCommands.LineFeed]); //LF
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue([PrinterCommands.LineFeed]); //LF

            //Set up for the image
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue(PrinterCommands.LineSpacing(8)); //ESC 3 8
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue([PrinterCommands.ESC, PrinterCommands.Asterix, PrinterCommands.EightDotSingleDensity, (byte)8, (byte)0]); //ESC * 0 8 0 image 8 pixels wide
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue([(byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)4, (byte)8, (byte)16, (byte)32, (byte)64, (byte)128]); //Forward slash in pixels
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue([PrinterCommands.LineFeed]); //LF

            WriteBuffer.Enqueue(PrinterCommands.LineSpacing(8)); //ESC 3 8
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue([PrinterCommands.ESC, PrinterCommands.Asterix, PrinterCommands.EightDotSingleDensity, (byte)8, (byte)0]); //ESC * 0 8 0 image 8 pixels wide
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue([(byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)4, (byte)8, (byte)16, (byte)32, (byte)64, (byte)128]); //Forward slash in pixels
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue([PrinterCommands.LineFeed]); //LF

            // at this point the line spacing should return to normal 30dots
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue([PrinterCommands.LineFeed]); //LF
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue("End printing".ToCharArray().Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray());
            WriteBuffer.Enqueue([PrinterCommands.LineFeed]); //LF

            // send the commands to the printer
            foreach (var x in WriteBuffer)
                RawPrinterHelper.SendBytesToPrinter("POS-58", x);
        }
    }
}


What programming language, API, or library are you using? It would be better if you could provide a short, complete code snippet that can be used to reproduce the problem and investigate it. Also, please include the vendor and model of the printer in question. Please refer to this help article for more information. How do I ask a good question?, How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

C#, its raw ESC commands, no libraries other than using the winspool dll. Its Netum 1809dd.

If you're using a program you created yourself, try creating the entire print request data as a binary file. By analyzing that with my tool kunif/EscPosUtils v0.4.0.0, you'll be able to determine whether the print request was made correctly.

did you try my code? what results did you get

I haven't tried your code. However, I think this is a method of investigation that can be applied if you encounter any problems in the future. As long as your printer does not deviate from Epson's ESC/POS specifications.

just try the code provided. I cannot work out how to use your utils sorry.

I don't have any idea about using ThermalPrinting; or var printer = new Printer(); in your source code, and it seems like it would take a lot of work to modify it, so I don't feel like trying it. If you can't use my tool, why not try comparing the data created with your program with the data created with other tools such as this EPSON tool or a free library? Send Data Tool, lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET

copy and paste the code you asked for in a c# console app :) i define it all in code ESCPOS.NET does not use ESC * it uses GS V

The send data tool was a good shout, sending 1Bh 2Ah 0 8 0
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128
0Ah i get the same results, a forward slash but with and underline. can you test on your printer?

Such print command data looks normal. If you are experiencing problems with the print results, check the specifications of the printer you are using. Or, if you have a printer from another vendor, such as Epson, why not compare the print results with that?

as i said originally netum have confirmed they support it, i dont have another printer. did yours just print a diagonal line or did you also see an underline?

Again, I haven't done any actual printing tests. Let's wait for someone to try it. Perhaps it's a problem specific to the printer you're using.

try using your suggestion and send the commands using the Send Data Tool. I would be interested to know if your printer prints it correctly using your suggestions
